# i have an error titled: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined" and cannot fix it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot use an advanced command handler and it isn't working.

**Error Message:**

```
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bryce\OneDrive\Desktop\bot\main.js:76:39)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\bryce\OneDrive\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\bryce\OneDrive\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)     
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\bryce\OneDrive\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\bryce\OneDrive\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\bryce\OneDrive\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\bryce\OneDrive\Desktop\bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

**main.js**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '='

const fs = require('fs');

// create the collection
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

// get an array of every file in the commands folder
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

// iterate a function through every file
for (file of commandFiles) {
 const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 console.log(file)
 
 // map the command to the collection with the key as the command name, 
 // and the value as the whole exported object
 client.commands.set(command.name, command);
};

client.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()

    if(command === 'twitch'){
        message.channel.send('https://www.twitch.tv/gamergirlspeed');
    }else if (command == 'youtube'){
        message.channel.send('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHN61ta8sZ-EkJ6JvlGRkng');
    }else if (command == 'tiktok'){
        message.channel.send('https://www.tiktok.com/@gamergirlspeed?lang=en ')
    }else if (command == 'help'){
        message.channel.send('**| =twitch**\n**| =youtube**\n**| =tiktok**\n**| =epic**\n**| =mods**\n**| =version**\n**| =author**\n**| =purge (broken)**\n**| =twitter**\n**| =switch**\n**| =rule1**\n**| =rule2**\n**| =rule3**\n**| =rule4**\n**| =rule5**\n**| =rule6**\n**| =rule7**\n**| =rule8**\n**| =rule9**\n**| =botcommands**')
    }else if (command == 'epic'){
        message.channel.send("Speed's Epic account is: Speed_Ster06")
    }else if (command == 'mods'){
        message.channel.send("Speed_Ster06's current mods are: FyreFoxe, RAPHBOSS")
    }else if (command == 'version'){
        message.channel.send("FyreFoxe's SpeedForce Bot is in version 1.7")
    }else if (command == 'author'){
        message.channel.send('SpeedForce Is Created by Bravmi#6740')
    }else if (command == 'twitter'){
        message.channel.send('https://twitter.com/GamerGirlSpeed1 ')
    }else if (command == 'playstation'){
        message.command.send("Speed's Playstation Account is: Speed_Ster06")
    }else if (command == 'switch'){
        message.channel.send("Speed's Switch Account is: SpeedSter6")
    }else if (command === 'purge'){
        client.commands.get('purge').execute(message,args);
    }else if (command == 'rule1'){
        message.channel.send('Do not spam')
    }else if (command == 'rule2'){
        message.channel.send("Don't be mean to others, It's just not nice.")
    }else if (command == 'rule3'){
        message.channel.send("No NSFW, It's just, we don't do that here.")
    }else if (command == 'rule4'){
        message.channel.send("No raiding, I think it's pretty clear what the punishment would be if you did.")
    }else if (command == 'rule5'){
        message.channel.send(" Don't boycott the discord/minecraft server.")
    }else if (command == 'rule6'){
        message.channel.send("Don't beg for roles.")
    }else if (command == 'rule7'){
        message.channel.send("Don’t advertise unless in the correct channel.")
    }else if (command == 'rule8'){
        message.channel.send("Don't put clips in the clips channel that aren't from my stream.")
    }else if (command == 'rule9'){
        message.channel.send("Rules are based upon logic or common sense. Don't do things that seem bad, only because it's 'Not a rule'.")
    }else if (command == 'botcommands'){
        message.channel.send('Bot Commands:\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n**1.** “!rank” shows you your rank level\n**2.** “!levels” shows you a leader board of all the other people’s levels\n**3.** “!help” helps find out information about commands\n**4.** “!links” shows the links to my YouTube and Twitch channels\n**5.** “!d bump” help show the discord server to other people\n**6.** “=help” Shows you all the cmds you can do with our custom SpeedForce Bot made by FyreFoxe\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    }else if (command === 'warn'){
        client.commands.get('warn.js').execute(message, args);
    }
    //else if (command === 'kick'){
        //client.commands.get('kick').execute(message, args)
    //}else if (command === 'ban'){
        //client.commands.get('ban').execute(message, args)
    //}
});

//Copyright LightSide Development, 2021

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Online!')
    setInterval(() => {
        targetGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('782068409646448640')
        if(targetGuild) {
            client.user.setActivity({ name: targetGuild.memberCount + ' SpeedSters!', type: 'WATCHING' }, { name: 'with commands!', type: 'PLAYING' }, { name: 'You...', type: 'WATCHING' })
                  .then(console.log)
                  .catch(console.error);
        }
  }, 1000 * 60 * 1);

});

client.login('expunged')
```

**warn.js**

```
const Discord = reqire("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const ms = require("ms");
let warns = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./warnings.json", "utf8"));

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

//=warn @name <reason>
 if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MEMBERS")) return message.reply("You don't have permission!");
 let wUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0])
 if(!wUser) return message.reply("The user specified does not exist!")
 if(wUser.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("You cannot warn them!");
 let reason = args.join(" ").slice(22);

 if(!warns[wUser.id]) warns[wUser.id] = {
    warns: 0
 };

  warns[wUser.id].warns++;

   fs.writeFile("./warnings.json", JSON.stringify(warns), (error) => {
     if (err) console.log(error);
   });

   let warnEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
   .setDescription("Warns")
   .setAuthor(message.author.username)
   .setColor("#fc6400")
   .addField("Warned User", `<@${wUser.tag}>`)
   .addField("Warned in", message.channel)
   .addField("Number of Warnings", warns[wUser.id].warns)
   .addField("Reason", reason)

   let warnchannel = message.guild.channels.find(`name`, "warnings");
   if(!warnchannel) return message.reply("The Logging channel has been deleted or renamed, contact Bravmi#6740");

   warnchannel.send(warnEmbed);

   if(warns[wUser.id].warns == 5){
     message.guild.member(wUser).ban(reason);
     warnchannel.send(`${wUser.tag} has been banned for ${reason}`)
   }

}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "warn"
}
```

the error occurs when i use the warn command, it crashes the bot and gives me the error message and i don't know what to do.

i have tried looking at it with some friends and they don't know what to do either, is there any way to fix it?

Comment: "I have tried looking at it with some friends and they don't know what to do either, is there any way to fix it?" > Try to make new friends?   More seriously, I don't know any discord so sorry if this is stupid, but shouldn't it be `client.commands.get('warn')` instead of `client.commands.get('warn.js')`?

Comment: it already has a filter to always be .js files

Comment: No, because you do `client.commands.set(command.name, command);`, which sets the key to `command.name` You set the name to `warn`. Your structure is very strange, have you taken a look at [The DJS Command Handler Guide](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/)

Answer (score 0):

The error "Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined" means exactly what it says.
In your case, you are trying to call the function "execute" on an object that does not exist.

The error is even giving you the line number that it is occurring "(C:\Users\bryce\OneDrive\Desktop\bot\main.js:76:39)".

Without line numbers in the code you posted above, I can't be sure, but it looks to me like the offending code is.

```
client.commands.get('warn.js').execute(message, args);
```

Which means `client.commands.get('warn.js')` is not returning an object. ie. calling the function `client.commands.get('warn.js')` is returning undefined.

I dare say, you may want to try `client.commands.get('warn').execute(message, args)`

Answer (score 0):

When you add your files to the collection at the start of your file you use `client.commands.set(command.name, command);`. This sets the key in the collection to the name of the command.

However, in your command file you use the following code `module.exports.help = { name: "warn" }` and there is no definition of what should be `module.exports.name`.

I would suggest changing the `module.exports.help` to `module.exports` and then remove the `.js` from all lines where you have `client.commands.get('...')`